# QToolButton Image with text

Tags: image, qt, button, pyqt, pyqt4

I am having image with text on `QToolbutton` . I want to fix the text position so it always be at same position irrespective of height of the image like here text `"asd"` and `"peter"` are on different position and I want text always be at that position where `"peter"` text is

[image]

Comment: The easiest way would be to make all your images a constant size. You can pad out any that are too small.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yes i did that but i am more interested to have some solution with Qt .

Comment: But that is a Qt solution. Create a transparent QPixmap of the proper constant size. Fill it with Qt::transparent. Then paint your picture to it. Otherwise you will have to look into QStyleSheet and completely define your button, or do a custom paintEvent

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,i tried one more thing that i define the QIconSize but it didnt help me , do u think it should work like that or i am doing something wrong

Comment: Just defining the icon size is probably not enough. It is just a constraint. I was talking about padding your images out to uniform sizes. I will try and put together an example and post an answer.

Comment: Thanks jdi , I already tried that and it works for me but i was thinking might be there is any other way through which i can control the position of text , but i guess there is no except this way

Comment: There are other ways. I only said this was the easiest. Other ways involve a custom paintEvent for the button or a full stylesheet definition.